# Can't see `docker-compose` logs for failed container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm starting my images via `docker-compose` in detached mode, like so:

```
docker-compose up -d --no-build --force-recreate my-api
```

Which shows this:

> ERROR: for my-api  Container "01f28210da4c" exited with code 139.
> Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
> Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

How can i see the logs, as to why it failed?

I tried this:

```
docker-compose logs -f my-api
```

But it just shows:

```
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
Attaching to
```

Not sure why it's cut off...

Note: this is running on GitHub actions, if that matters.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try running it in non detached mode, skip the `-d` will get logs from the start this way.

Comment: @s3vt same result.